# add editable row in extjs grid, and already open for editing at the same time

Tags: extjs

I'm working on a grid and I don't want to create a pop up to insert data, so I'm going to insert a line in the already open grid for editing, insert the data and save them afterwards

I tried that, but it just adds the empty line. Does not open for editing

**Grid**

```
Ext.define('MONITORING.mapMonitor.timeManager.Grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Grid',
    xtype: 'map-monitor-time-manager-grid',
    requires: [
        'Ext.grid.plugin.PagingToolbar',
        'Ext.grid.rowedit.Plugin',
    ],
    bind: {
        store: '{schedules}',
    },
    selectable: {
        checkbox: true
    },
    plugins: {
        pagingtoolbar: true,
        rowedit: {
            id: 'rowediting',
        },
    },
    listeners: {
        edit: 'onEdit',
    },
    title: UITEXT.MAP_MONITOR_TIME_MANAGER_TITLE,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        docked: 'top',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            iconCls: "x-fa fa-plus",
            text: UITEXT.BUTTON_ADD,
            handler: "addRow",
        }, '->', {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            placeholder: UITEXT.GENERAL_SEARCH,
            listeners: {
                keyup: 'onFilterNameKeyup'
            }
        }]
    }],
    columns: [{
        text: UITEXT.GENERAL_DESCRIPTION,
        dataIndex: 'descricao',
        sortable: false,
        flex: 1,
        editable: true,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
        }
    }, {
        text: UITEXT.SETTINGS_COUPONS_START,
        dataIndex: 'hora_inicial',
        sortable: false,
        flex: 0.3,
        align: 'center',
        editable: true,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'timefield',
        }
    }, {
        text: UITEXT.MONITORING_MAIN_THE_END,
        dataIndex: 'hora_final',
        sortable: false,
        flex: 0.3,
        align: 'center',
        editable: true,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'timefield',
        }
    },{
        align: 'center',
        width: 60,
        cell: {
            tools: {
                remove: {
                    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-trash',
                    handler: 'onRemove'
                }
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

**Controller**

```
    addRow: function () {
        const me = this;
        const grid = me.getView();
        const store = grid.getViewModel().getStore('schedules');
        const newRecord = store.insert(0, {})[0];
        grid.getPlugin('rowediting').startEdit(newRecord, 0);
        // I tried that way too
        // me.findPlugin('rowediting').startEdit(newRecord);
    },
```

**Store**

```
Ext.define('MONITORING.mapMonitor.timeManager.MainModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.map-monitor-time-manager',
    stores: {
        schedules: {
            model: 'MONITORING.model.mapmonitor.Openinghours',
            autoLoad: true,
            pageSize: 20,
        }
    }
});
```

**Model**

```
Ext.define('MONITORING.model.mapmonitor.Openinghours', {
    extend: 'MONITORING.model.Base',
    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        type: 'integer'
    }, {
        name: 'hora_inicial',
        type: 'string',
    }, {
        name: 'hora_final',
        type: 'string',
    }, {
        name: 'descricao',
        type: 'string'
    }],
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: `${Ext.manifest.apiUrl}/mapmonitor/hostmanagement-openinghours`,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data',
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
        },
    }
});
```

I get an error in the startEdit() function

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'startEdit')**

thanks in advance

Start editing newline automatically

**grid.getPlugin('rowediting').startEdit(newRowIndex, 0);**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the id you are passing to grid.getPlugin('rowedit') matches the actual id of the row editing plugin.Also you can directly pass the record here startEdit(newRecord, 0).Please check the below sample code for reference,

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('MyApp.model.UserDataModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['descricao', 'hora_inicial', 'hora_final'],
        });

        Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.viewmodel', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
            alias: 'viewmodel.mainviewmodel',
            stores: {
                usersStore: {
                    model: 'MyApp.model.UserDataModel',
                    data: [{
                        descricao: "Meeting 1",
                        hora_inicial: "10:00 AM",
                        hora_final: "11:00 AM"
                    }, {
                        descricao: "Meeting 2",
                        hora_inicial: "10:00 AM",
                        hora_final: "11:00 AM"
                    }, {
                        descricao: "Meeting 3",
                        hora_inicial: "10:00 AM",
                        hora_final: "11:00 AM"
                    }],
                }
            }
        });

        Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.MainView', {
            extend: 'Ext.grid.Grid',
            xtype: 'mainview',
            viewModel: 'mainviewmodel',
            controller: 'gridcntr',
            title: 'User Data',
            requires: [
                'Ext.grid.plugin.PagingToolbar',
                'MyApp.view.main.viewmodel',
                'Ext.grid.rowedit.Plugin',
                'MyApp.model.UserDataModel'
            ],
            bind: {
                store: '{usersStore}'
            },
            selectable: {
                checkbox: true
            },
            plugins: {
                pagingtoolbar: true,
                rowedit: {
                    id: "rowediting"
                }
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                docked: 'top',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    iconCls: "x-fa fa-plus",
                    text: "Addrow",
                    handler: "addRow",
                }, '->', {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    placeholder: "search",
                    listeners: {
                        keyup: 'onFilterNameKeyup'
                    }
                }]
            }],
            columns: [{
                text: "DESCRIPTION",
                dataIndex: 'descricao',
                sortable: false,
                flex: 1,
                editable: true,
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                }
            }, {
                text: "START",
                dataIndex: 'hora_inicial',
                sortable: false,
                flex: 0.3,
                align: 'center',
                editable: true,
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'timefield',
                }
            }, {
                text: "FINAL",
                dataIndex: 'hora_final',
                sortable: false,
                flex: 0.3,
                align: 'center',
                editable: true,
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'timefield',
                }
            }, {
                align: 'center',
                width: 60,
                cell: {
                    tools: {
                        remove: {
                            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-trash',
                            handler: 'onRemove'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        });

        Ext.define('GridController', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
            alias: 'controller.gridcntr',
            addRow: function () {
                var grid = this.getView();
                var store = grid.getStore();
                var newRow = store.add({
                    descricao: '',
                    hora_inicial: '',
                    hora_final: '',
                })[0];
                grid.getPlugin('rowediting').startEdit(newRow, 0);
            }
        });

        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'mainview'
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: continuous with the same error, take a look at the question again, I edited it and included the grid

Comment: I refis everything as you explain and I continue with the same error. I added the store in the question

Comment: couldnt replicate the issue..! tried creating an example with the data you have provided..works fine..please check! make sure you have updated the crct url..! https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3p1i

Answer (score -2):

Try accessing the row editing plugin via indexing and then call the startEdit function.
grid.plugins[1].startEdit(newRecord, 0);